# Let $F:M\rightarrow N$ and $G:N\rightarrow P$ be surface transformation. Show that $(G\circ F)^{*}=F^{*}\circ G^{*}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, closed-form, surfaces, transformation

$Let F:M\rightarrow N$ and $G:N\rightarrow P$ be surface transformation. Show that $$(G\circ F)^{*}=F^{*}\circ G^{*}$$

**Here is definition :**  Let $F:M\rightarrow N$ transformation of surfaces.

**$i$**) If $\phi$ is $0$-form then $F^{*}\phi =\phi\circ F$ and it's also $0$-form.

**$ii$**)If $\phi$ is $1$-form then for every $v$ ($v$ is tangent vector) $F^{*}\phi(v) =\phi(F_{*}(v))$

**$iii$**) If $\phi$ is $2$-form then for every $v,w$ (both tangent vector) $F^{*}\phi(v,w) =\phi(F_{*}(v),F_{*}(w))$

We should show that $(G\circ F)^{*}=F^{*}\circ G^{*}$ for all cases. Let $\phi$ is $0$-form then $$(G\circ F)^{*}(\phi )=\phi\circ (G\circ F)=(\phi \circ G)\circ F=F^{*}(\phi\circ G)=F^{*}(G^{*}(\phi ))=(F^{*}\circ G^{*})(\phi )$$

But I couldn't show for $1$-form and $2$-form. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: By definition $\left((G\circ F)^* \phi\right)(v,w) = \phi\left(\left(G \circ F\right)_*v,\left(G\circ F\right)_*w \right)$. To conclude, use the chain-rule: $(G\circ F)_* = G_* \circ F_*$.

Comment: @Didier I used but I couldn't get the solution for both $ii$) and $iii$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof for $1$-forms, the other cases being similar.

Let $v$ be a vector field on $M$ and $\phi$ be a $1$-form on $P$. Then:
\begin{align}
\left((G\circ F)^*\phi\right)(v) &= \phi\left((G\circ F)_* v \right) \\
&= \phi\left( \left(G_* \circ F_*\right) v\right) & \text{(chain rule)}\\
&= \phi\left(G_*\left(F_* v\right)\right) \\
&= G^* \left(\phi \right)(F_*v)\\
&= F^* \left(G^*\phi\right)(v)\\
&= \left(F^* \circ G^*\right)(\phi)(v)
\end{align}

Comment: * symbol should be top of the $(GoF)$ in  first equation (left part)

Comment: @softglance Of course! Thank you for noticing that typo

Comment: thanks for the answer btw

Comment: For $iii)$ cases , How can I distrubute $\phi ((G\circ F)_{*}v,(G\circ F)_{*}w)\phi ((G\circ F)_{*}v,(G\circ F)_{*}w)=\phi ((G_{*}F_{*}(v),G_{*}F_{*}(w))$?

Comment: @softglance Your last term is the definition of $G^*\phi(F_*v,F_*w)$

Comment: Okay I get it now , thank you again